# How to set a value from an element in a list during a loop in Python. Sudoku solver

Tags: python, algorithm, iterator, nested-lists, sudoku

I'm trying to create a Sudoku Solver (yes I know there are plenty of codes out there but I'm trying to do it on my own). Anyway, for the sake of simplicity, I'll use a 4x4 grid in my example. I have assigned the possible values of each cell to their respective cell like in *grid* below.

```
original_grid = [['A1','A2','A3','A4'],['B1','B2',1,3],['C1',2,3,'C4'],['D1',3,'D3',2]]
grid = [[[1,2,3,4],[1,4],[2,4],[4]],[[2,4],[4],1,3],[[1,4],2,3,[1,4]],[[1,4],3,[4],2]]
```

Suppose I have a function *IsSolved()* that checks for the completion of the sudoku. How do I iterate through the grid, assigning the first possible value in the lists assigned to "empty" cells, then reiterate through the grid again, assigning the next possible value of the last empty cell if *IsSolved()* returns False? Or is this even doable?

Comment: I think [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_UYXzGuqvM) should help

Comment: It was. Thank you! @KJTHoward